# Расположение слов в предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь, порядок-слов

Предложение звучит так: "В этом году заплатить налоги нужно до 3 декабря". Верна ли конструкция "…заплатить налоги нужно…"?

Comment: Вы про грамматику? Я не вижу повода в ней сомневаться. Уточните вопрос, что конкретно вызвало у вас вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

***В этом году заплатить налОги // нужно до 3 декабрЯ.***

Всё верно, это **актуальное деление** предложения на тему и рему, то есть предмет сообщения и сообщение об этом  предмете (иначе говоря, о чем говорим и что говорим).

Поэтому **изменен прямой порядок слов** в исходном сочетании "нужно заплатить налоги".

Почему использовано именно такое деление? Дело в том, что мы обычно выделяем ударением конечное слово в каждой части. В данном случае выделены **ключевые слова** *налоги* и *декабря*.